# Image Fusion using Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, fusion

I want to make a fusion of two images using this example:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/examples/image-fusion.html?prodcode=WA&language=en

I wrote this:

```
X1 = imread('G:\an1.jpg');
 X2 = imread('G:\an2.jpg');
 XFUSmean = wfusimg(X1,X2,'db2',1,'mean','mean');
 XFUSmaxmin = wfusimg(X1,X2,'db2',1,'max','min');
 myColorMap = jet(256);
 colormap(myColorMap);
 subplot(221), image(X1), axis square, title('Mask')
subplot(222), image(X2), axis square, title('Bust')
subplot(223), image(XFUSmean), axis square,
title('Synthesized image, mean-mean')
subplot(224), image(XFUSmaxmin), axis square,
title('Synthesized image, max-min')
```

But i receive an error:
Error using image
TrueColor CData contains element out of range 0.0 <= value <= 1.0

Comment: I know that i have to scale my images to the range [0,1].

Comment: but how can i do that?

Comment: Try
X1 = im2double(imread('G:\an1.jpg'));
or simply
X1 = double(imread('G:\an1.jpg'))/255;

Comment: clear all
 X1 = imread('G:\an1.jpg');
 X2 = imread('G:\an2.jpg');
 XFUSmean = wfusimg(X1,X2,'db2',1,'mean','mean');
 XFUSmaxmin = wfusimg(X1,X2,'db2',1,'max','min');
 myColorMap = jet(256);
 colormap(myColorMap);
 X1 = double(imread('G:\an1.jpg'))/255;
 X2 = double(imread('G:\an2.jpg'))/255;
 subplot(221), image(X1), axis square, title('Mask')
subplot(222), image(X2), axis square, title('Bust')
subplot(223), image(XFUSmean), axis square,
title('Synthesized image, mean-mean')
subplot(224), image(XFUSmaxmin), axis square,
title('Synthesized image, max-min')

Comment: Again there is an error message. Error using image
TrueColor CData contains element out of range 0.0 <= value <= 1.0